# Socket.IO get connected clients list

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm having a heck of a time finding documentation on `io.sockets.clients()` so I can retrieve the connected clients id, username, etc. When I `alert(io.sockets.clients().length.toString());` it gives me the correct number, but I need to find the structure of the array. Is there a way I can figure out the array without knowing the structure? Much like php's `print_r()`?

Code so far:

```
socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
    var clients = io.sockets.clients();
    socket.emit('users', clients);
});

socket.on('users', function(usernames) {
    for(var client in usernames) {
        console.log(usernames[client].id + ' disconnected: ' +     usernames[client].disconnected)
    }
});
```

I receive this error after 'switchRoom' is fired

```
/home/ed/socket/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/parser.js:81
data = JSON.stringify(ev);
              ^
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
at Object.stringify (native)
at Object.encodePacket (/home/ed/socket/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/parser.js:81:19)
at Socket.packet (/home/ed/socket/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:202:21)
at Socket.emit (/home/ed/socket/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:351:15)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ed/socket/chat/app.js:58:10)
at Socket.$emit (events.js:64:17)
at SocketNamespace.handlePacket (/home/ed/socket/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:331:20)
at Manager.onClientMessage (/home/ed/socket/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:436:38)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/ed/socket/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transport.js:387:20)
at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/ed/socket/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-07-12.js:38:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing this on the client side (in the browser) or on the server side? You mention using `alert`, but I'm not aware of a `clients()` method on the client side that does what you want.

On the server side, `clients()` returns an array of `Socket`s [as defined by this method](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/6074795b191248fa36db37b89df3c95e1520adcb/lib/namespace.js#L44-61):

```
/**
 * Retrieves all clients as Socket instances as an array.
 *
 * @api public
 */

SocketNamespace.prototype.clients = function (room) {
  var room = this.name + (room !== undefined ?
     '/' + room : '');

  if (!this.manager.rooms[room]) {
    return [];
  }

  return this.manager.rooms[room].map(function (id) {
    return this.socket(id);
  }, this);
};
```

The Node.js console and browsers with dev tools provide a `console` object that allows debugging; generally, you can call `console.log(something)` where `something` pretty much anything; in the case of an object, the details of the object will be enumerated in one way or another.

[Edit]

Since you're already using `socket.set` to store the username, perhaps you can try something like this:

```
// server

socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
  ...
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    socket.get('username', function (err, name) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('disconnected', name);
    });
  });
  ...
});

// client

socket.on('connect', function () {
  ...
  socket.on('disconnected', function(name) {
    console.log(name + " disconnected.");
  });
  ...
});
```

Comment: I have added my current code to show more in depth of what is happening. This is done on the server (app.js) and nothing gets pushed to the console.

Comment: I assume the first part is on the server and the second is on the client? `io.sockets.clients()` returns an array of `Socket` objects; you cannot send them over the Internet to the client. You'll need to get the username data out of them and send, say, an array of strings or something instead. Are you using `socket.set` to set the username? If not, how are you keeping track of them?

Comment: I use `socket.set('username', 'MyName')` and `socket.set('id', socket.id)` is there a way to grab the set vars and then possibly `.emit` to the client?

Comment: that works great for getting a single user that disconnects. However I need to get a list of all connected (preferrably in channel 'x') usernames when a custom event fires. if `io.socket.clients()` can only be seen/modified in server can I emit the `.clients()` username(s) to the client?

Comment: You could iterate over the array of Sockets and `get` the "username" for each one, add it to an array, and then when you're done iterating, send the array to the client, but the asynchronous nature of `get` may make this difficult. Alternatively, you can maintain an array of usernames, modified when a new socket connects, and just ship that off to the client.